# Authorize.Net with ActiveMerchant doesn't work in production mode

Tags: authorize.net, activemerchant

Everything works fine in development mode! Fake transactions were successful, and I got receipts from Authorize.Net. But when I used the real login id and transaction key in production, it didn't work. I called Authorize.Net, they said the transaction never hit their system and said I need to post to their live url instead of test url. I followed tutorials from other websites and none of them tells to set up urls for Authorize.Net.

This is my `production.rb`

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :production

::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetGateway.new(
  :login    => HADEAN_CONFIG['authnet']['login'],
  :password => HADEAN_CONFIG['authnet']['password'],
  :test     => false
)
```

and `orders_controller.rb`

```
def update
@order = session_admin_order
@order.ip_address = request.remote_ip

@credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(cc_params)

address = @order.bill_address.cc_params

if @order.complete?
  #CartItem.mark_items_purchased(session_cart, @order)
  session_admin_cart.mark_items_purchased(@order)
  flash[:error] = I18n.t('the_order_purchased')
  redirect_to admin_history_order_url(@order)
elsif @credit_card.valid?
  if response = @order.create_invoice(@credit_card,
                                      @order.credited_total,
                                      {:email => @order.email, :billing_address=> address, :ip=> @order.ip_address },
                                      @order.amount_to_credit)
    if response.succeeded?
      ##  MARK items as purchased
      #CartItem.mark_items_purchased(session_cart, @order)
      @order.remove_user_store_credits
      session_admin_cart.mark_items_purchased(@order)
      order_completed!
      Notifier.order_confirmation(@order, invoice).deliver rescue puts( 'do nothing...  dont blow up over an email')
      redirect_to admin_history_order_url(@order)
    else
      form_info
      flash[:error] =  [I18n.t('could_not_process'), I18n.t('the_order')].join(' ')
      render :action => "show"
    end
  else
    form_info
    flash[:error] = [I18n.t('could_not_process'), I18n.t('the_credit_card')].join(' ')
    render :action => 'show'
  end
else
  form_info
  flash[:error] = [I18n.t('credit_card'), I18n.t('is_not_valid')].join(' ')
  render :action => 'show'
end
```

end

```
private

def form_info
```

end

```
def cc_params
{
      :type               => params[:type],
      :number             => params[:number],
      :verification_value => params[:verification_value],
      :month              => params[:month],
      :year               => params[:year],
      :first_name         => params[:first_name],
      :last_name          => params[:last_name]
} end
```

Comment: Your settings look correct to me. What kind of errors are you seeing?

Comment: could not process error from flash[:error] = [I18n.t('could_not_process'), I18n.t('the_credit_card')].join(' ').

Comment: BTW I used a legit card and the test mode on authorize.net was off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making this small change:

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :production
ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetCimGateway.new( 
  :login    => HADEAN_CONFIG['authnet']['login'],
  :password => HADEAN_CONFIG['authnet']['password']
)
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work. 2012-07-31T20:42:57+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant GATEWAY)    The authorize.net guy told me I was using aim but I'm not sure.